# python webcam recorder with opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, format, codec

I've write webcam recorder by python and opencv .
now I have problem , I'm using of xvid codec for record video and when run my program on other system which not have xvid codec my program not work . 
how i can solve it ? i don't want to install xvid on system

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy 
import time
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(5)
i=0
if camera:
   try:
      video  = cv2.VideoWriter()
      fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
      video.open('video.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (int(camera.get(3)), int(camera.get(4))))
      while True and i<10 :
         f,img = camera.read()
         video.write(img)
         i=i+1
   except:
      pass
video.release()
```

Comment: Once you have a dependency in any code in any language, you have to fulfil that dependency. So either do not use that codec, but an already installed one, or record the raw stream and encode it later.

Comment: opencv3.0 has its own buildin mjpg encoder/decoder (and maybe even an avi one)